# Static query error with Gatsby in Storybook

Tags: gatsby, storybook

I've been trying to implement Storybook into my Gatsby project and have run into several errors. [I've been following the guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/visual-testing-with-storybook/) but when I try to run Storybook with the updated main.js and preview.js files, I get the following build error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`. This refers to `rules[0]` in the following;

```
config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins.push(
    require.resolve("babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries")
);
```

I've tried taking this code block out and I get an error stating `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (99:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.` I assume from that that removing the block isn't an option.

I've run `console.log(config.module.rules[0])` at the start of the `webpackFinal` method and it logs `{ test: /\.m?js$/, type: 'javascript/auto' }`, so I don't know why it's undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've copied my full main.js (well, actually main.ts) file below;

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";
import "react";

const React = require("react");

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [
      /node_modules\/(?!(gatsby|gatsby-script)\/)/,
    ];

    // Use correct react-dom depending on React version.
    if (parseInt(React.version) <= 18) {
      config.externals = ["react-dom/client"];
    }

    // Remove core-js to prevent issues with Storybook
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [/core-js/];
    // Use babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries to remove static queries from components when rendering in storybook
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins.push(
      require.resolve("babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries")
    );

    config.resolve.mainFields = ["browser", "module", "main"];
    return config;
  },
};
export default config;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

> config.module.rules[2]

instead of

> config.module.rules[0]

That worked for me.